# Failed to de-identify patient name in DICOM tag (0010, 0010) by calling API "deidentify()" in library @googleapis/healthcare

Tags: node.js, google-healthcare-api

I am working on a Cloud service for de-identifying DICOM data in a Google Healthcare DICOM store (not DICOM set). I want to replace patient name (value in DICOM tag (0010, 0010)) with a special char (such as '*') or with the name of the value's infoType (such as 'PERSON_NAME').

I tried following test code, NONE of them changed patient Name (i.e. After "deidentify()" call, the patient name in DICOM tag (0010,0010) remains same). Anything  wrong in the code ?

Test Code #1:

```
const res = await healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.dicomStores.deidentify({           
          sourceStore: sourceStore,
          destinationStore: destinationStore,
          resource: { 
            config: {
             dicom: {  
               filterProfile: 'DEIDENTIFY_TAG_CONTENTS',  
             }, 
             text: {
              transformations: [ 
                {
                  infoTypes:['PERSON_NAME'], 
                  characterMaskConfig:{maskingCharacter: ''}
                }
              ]
            },  
             image: {
               textRedactionMode: 'REDACT_SENSITIVE_TEXT',
             }, 
           }, 
           filterConfig: { 
           },  
          },
        });
```

Test Code #2:

```
const res = await healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.dicomStores.deidentify({           
          sourceStore: sourceStore,
          destinationStore: destinationStore,   
          resource: { 
            config: {
             dicom: { 
               filterProfile: 'DEIDENTIFY_TAG_CONTENTS' 
             }, 
             text: {
              transformations: [
                {
                  infoTypes:['PERSON_NAME'], 
                  characterMaskConfig:{maskingCharacter: '*'}
                },                  
              ]
            },  
             image: {
               textRedactionMode: 'REDACT_SENSITIVE_TEXT',
             }, 
           }, 
           filterConfig: { 
           },  
          },
        });
```

Test Code #3:

```
const res = await healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.dicomStores.deidentify({         
          sourceStore: sourceStore,
          destinationStore: destinationStore,
          resource: { 
            config: {
             dicom: { 
               filterProfile: 'DEIDENTIFY_TAG_CONTENTS' 
             }, 
             text: {
              transformations: [
                // replace relevant values with their infoTypes                 
                {
                  infoTypes: [],
                    replaceWithInfoTypeConfig: {}
                } ,                 
              ]
            },  
             image: {
               textRedactionMode: 'REDACT_SENSITIVE_TEXT',
             }, 
           }, 
           filterConfig: { 
           },  
          },
        });
```

Test Code #4:

```
const res = await healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.dicomStores.deidentify({          
          sourceStore: sourceStore,
          destinationStore: destinationStore,
          resource: { 
            config: {
             dicom: {  
               filterProfile: 'DEIDENTIFY_TAG_CONTENTS' 
             }, 
             text: {
              transformations: [
                {
                  infoTypes:['PERSON_NAME'],
                  redactConfig:{}, 
                },
                 
              ]
            },  
             image: {
               textRedactionMode: 'REDACT_SENSITIVE_TEXT',
             }, 
           }, 
           filterConfig: { 
           },  
          },
        });
```

Test  Code #5:

```
const res = await healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.dicomStores.deidentify({          
          sourceStore: sourceStore,
          destinationStore: destinationStore,
          resource: { 
            config: {
             dicom: {  
               filterProfile: 'DEIDENTIFY_TAG_CONTENTS' 
             }, 
             text: {
              transformations: [
                {
                  infoTypes:[],
                  redactConfig:{}, 
                }, 
              ]
            },  
             image: {
               textRedactionMode: 'REDACT_SENSITIVE_TEXT',
             }, 
           }, 
           filterConfig: { 
           },  
          },
        });
```

Test Code #6:

```
const res = await healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.dicomStores.deidentify({         
          sourceStore: sourceStore,
          destinationStore: destinationStore,
          resource: { 
            config: {
             dicom: { 
               filterProfile: 'DEIDENTIFY_TAG_CONTENTS' 
             }, 
             text: {
              transformations: [                  
              ]
            },  
             image: {
               textRedactionMode: 'REDACT_SENSITIVE_TEXT',
             }, 
           }, 
           filterConfig: { 
           },  
          },
        });
```

---

Related google  de-ide docs:
https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/reference/rest/v1/DeidentifyConfig#TagFilterProfile
https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/dicom-deidentify#default_dicom_infotypes

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: I tested out a few of your examples and options #2 and #3 worked for me. Is it possible that the operation failed for another reason? There may be something in Cloud Logging (you can find the link in the logsUrl field of the operation). Another option is maybe the operation hadn't finished yet when you checked the destination store?

Comment: Hi, Nik: Thank you so  much for your time and effort to test sample code! I tried  again, but still same thing to me.  #2 and # 3 not work for me: patient name is not changed. Which version of google healthcare client lib (node.js)? I used "V1". How did you create  the client object?  This is what I did:

Comment: const google = require('@googleapis/healthcare');

const healthcare = google.healthcare({
  version: 'v1',
  auth: new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    scopes: [GOOGLE_APIS_CLOUD_PLATFORM],
    keyFile: 'C:/Discover-Test-Acct/ipi-anonymizationservice.json'
  }),
});

Comment: I checked  operation status  in  Cloud logging, didn't find any error. The de-id operation  seems  finished successfully. Event after a while, when I can call "healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.dicomStores.searchForInstances())" to get  all instances from destination store,  the patient  name is still SAME, no change.

Comment: Step 1: Create a multipart image file using https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/dicomweb#storing_dicom_data
Step 2: Replace the instance metadata with the metadata sample here https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/how-tos/dicom-deidentify#de-identifying_dicom_tags
Step 3: Run the following code https://pastebin.com/sAKwVTUM

Comment: Hi, Nik: Thank you so much for the detailed steps.  I have my own way to store DICOM instance to DICOM store. Now the code for de-identification is working as expected! Really appreciate your help!